# $\Delta F' / \Delta x'$ is approximately twice as large as $\Delta F / \Delta x$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

I am currently studying the textbook *Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces*, by Pavel Grinfeld. On page 3, the author begins with the following motivating example:

> What is the gradient of a function $F$ and a point $P$? You are familiar with two definitions, one geometric and one analytical. According to the geometric definition, the gradient $\nabla F$ of $F$ is the vector that points in the direction of the greatest increase of the function $F$, and its magnitude equals the greatest rate of increase. According to the analytical definition that requires the presence of a coordinate system, the gradient of $F$ is the triplet of numbers
>
> $$\nabla F = \left( \dfrac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}, \dfrac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}} \right) \tag{1.1}$$
>
> Are the two definitions equivalent in some sense? If you believe that the connection is
>
> $$\nabla F = \dfrac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}\mathbf{i}  + \dfrac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}} \mathbf{j}\tag{1.2}$$
>
> where $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ are the coordinate basis, you are in for a surprise! Equation (1.2) can only be considered valid if it produces the same vector in all coordinate systems. You may not be familiar with the definition of a coordinate basis in general curvilinear coordinates, such as spherical coordinates. The appropriate definition will be given in Chap. 5. However, equation (1.2) yields different answers even for the two coordinate systems in Fig. 1.1.
>
> [image]
>
> For a more specific example, consider a temperature distribution $T$ in a two-dimensional rectangular room. Refer the interior of the room to a rectangular coordinate system $x$, $y$ where the coordinate lines are one meter apart. This coordinate system is illustrated on the left of Fig. 1.1. Express the temperature field in terms of these coordinates and construct the vector gradient $\nabla T$ according to equation (1.2).
>
> Alternatively, refer the interior of the room to another rectangular system $x'$, $y'$, illustrated on the right of Fig. 1.1), whose coordinate lines are two meters apart. For example, at a point where $x = 2$, the new coordinate $x'$ equals $1$. Therefore, the new coordinates and the old coordinates are related by the identities
>
> $$x = 2x' \ \ \ \ \ y = 2y' \tag{1.3}$$
>
> Now repeat the construction of the gradient according to equation (1.2) in the new coordinate system: refer the temperature field to the new coordinates, resulting in the function $F'(x', y')$, calculate the partial derivatives and evaluate the expression in equation (1.2), except with “primed” elements:
>
> $$(\nabla T)' = \dfrac{\partial{F'}}{\partial{x'}} \mathbf{i}' + \dfrac{\partial{F'}}{\partial{y'}} \mathbf{j}' \tag{1.4}$$
>
> How does $\nabla T$ compare to $(\nabla T)'$? The magnitudes of the new coordinate vectors $\mathbf{i}'$ and $\mathbf{j}'$ are double those of the old coordinate vectors $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$. What happens to the partial derivatives? Do they halve (this would be good) or do they double (this would be trouble)?
>
> They double! This is because in the new coordinates, quantities change twice as fast. In evaluating the rate of change with respect to, say, $x$, one increments $x$ by a small amount $\Delta x$, such as $\Delta x = 10^{-3}$, and determines how much the function $F(x, y)$ changes in response to that small change in $x$. When one evaluates the partial derivative with respect to $x'$ in the new coordinate system, the same increment in the new variable $x'$ is, in physical terms, twice as large. It results in twice as large a change $\Delta F'$ in the function $F'(x', y')$. Therefore, $\Delta F' / \Delta x'$ is approximately twice as large as $\Delta F / \Delta x$ and we conclude that partial derivatives double:
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial{F'(x', y')}}{\partial{x'}} = 2\dfrac{\partial{F(x, y)}}{\partial{x}} \tag{1.5}$$

The first point I'm seeking clarification on is a minor problem: (1.1) is actually a doublet, right? The author refers to it as a triplet.

The point that I'm uncomfortable with is the idea that $\Delta F' / \Delta x'$ is approximately twice as large as $\Delta F / \Delta x$. If we're increasing the denominator by $10^{-3}$, then why doesn't the numerator also increase by approximately the same amount, so that the result approximately cancels out to result in approximately the same value as before? I'm not satisfied that the author explains this clearly enough to make it evident.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

---

### **EDIT**

The first +50 bounty has expired, so I might as well post my thoughts so far, so that it might help others formulate an answer.

In trying to understand this, I had two streams of thought. The first stream of thought was focused on trying to understand (1.5), whilst the second stream of though was focused on trying to understand what I alluded to in my main post (which was the ideas behind the $\Delta F / \Delta x$ and $\Delta F' / \Delta x'$). It seems to me that an answer to the latter type of problem would naturally be suited to a real-analytic approach, so that's what I've been trying to do. I tried to understand the former by just using straightforward manipulations of the functions and their various implications. The main problem is that I don't have a lot of experience in real analysis, so I'm very unsure of my reasoning.

I am not claiming that this post is an answer to the questions I have; rather, it is an expansion of my main post. In this expansion, I present my thoughts in trying to understand this section of the textbook, as well as some new questions that arose in the process of my reasoning.

I am now going to post a second, larger bounty for this post. In addition to my original questions, I would appreciate it if people would review my reasoning here, and perhaps build upon it in their answer, and answer the questions that arose in this reasoning.

---

The first problem I see here is that we don't know the form of the function $F(x, y)$. It seems to me that this would have made things much easier. So we don't know whether, for instance, the function takes the form $F(x, y) = x + y$, and, therefore, $\nabla F = (1, 1)$, or whether the function takes some other form. I also wondered if we could use the antiderivative to recover the form of the function somehow, as is done to solve certain forms of differential equations, but I'm not sure whether that is possible/helpful in this situation. On the other hand, based on what I can infer from reasoning about this situation, **it may not matter what form the function takes**, or, rather, **we may not need to know the precise form of the function**, since **we are told that the function form is such that $x = 2x', y = 2y'$ and $\dfrac{\partial{F'(x', y')}}{\partial{x'}} = 2\dfrac{\partial{F(x, y)}}{\partial{x}}$**, which might already give us enough information to understand what's going on here without needing the precise form of the function.

---

### **The first part of my thoughts:**

So, we have that the change of coordinates

$$x = 2x', \ \ \ y = 2y'$$

leads to the new function

$$F'(x', y') = F' \left( \dfrac{x}{2}, \dfrac{y}{2} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} F' \left( x, y \right).$$

**Side-note:** This assumes that $F' \left( \dfrac{x}{2}, \dfrac{y}{2} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} F' \left( x, y \right)$. This begs the question: If we have a function of the form $F'(x', y') = F'\left( \dfrac{x}{2}, \dfrac{y}{2} \right)$, where $x = 2x'$ and $y = 2y'$ are a change of variables, then what conditions must be satisfied for us to be able to say that $F'(x', y') = F'\left( \dfrac{x}{2}, \dfrac{y}{2} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} F'\left( x, y \right)$? I ask that question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3531761/356308), but have, as of yet, received no answers. I proceed assuming that it is valid in this case.

**EDIT:** This property of functions seems to be referred to as "**homogeneity**" (see the aforementioned question for further details). So I proceed assuming that $F'$ is a **homogeneous function**.

Taking the partial derivatives with respect to $x$, we have

$$\dfrac{\partial{F'(x', y')}}{\partial{x'}} = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{\partial{F'\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}'} \Rightarrow 2 \dfrac{\partial{F'(x', y')}}{\partial{x'}} = \dfrac{\partial{F'\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}'}.$$

I wonder if $\dfrac{\partial{F'\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}'} = \dfrac{\partial{F\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}}$? Because then we would have that

$$\dfrac{\partial{F'(x', y')}}{\partial{x'}} = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{\partial{F'\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}'} \Rightarrow 2 \dfrac{\partial{F'(x', y')}}{\partial{x'}} = \dfrac{\partial{F'\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}'} = \dfrac{\partial{F\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}} \\ \therefore 2 \dfrac{\partial{F'(x', y')}}{\partial{x'}} = \dfrac{\partial{F\left( x, y \right)}}{\partial{x}},$$

as required.

---

### **The second part of my thoughts:**

Using the [definition of partial differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Formal_definition), I think we can proceed as follows:

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{\Delta F}{\Delta x} = \dfrac{\partial{F(x, y)}}{\partial{x}} &= \lim_{\Delta x \to 10^{-3}} \dfrac{F(x + \Delta x, y) - F(x, y)}{\Delta x} \\ &= \lim_{\Delta (2x') \to 10^{-3}} \dfrac{F(2x' + \Delta (2x'), 2y') - F(2x', 2y')}{\Delta (2x')} \\ &= \lim_{\Delta (x') \to \frac{10^{-3}}{2}} \dfrac{2[F(x' + \Delta (x'), y') - F(x', y')]}{2\Delta (x')} \ \ \text{(Assuming that $F$ is a **homogeneous function**.)} \\ &= \lim_{\Delta (x') \to \frac{10^{-3}}{2}} \dfrac{F(x' + \Delta (x'), y') - F(x', y')}{\Delta (x')} \end{align}$$

I'm not sure whether I made an error here or whether it's just a dead-end, but it seems to that proceeding in this way, using the definition of partial differentiation, is a good way to gain an understanding of what the author meant.

---

### **EDIT 2:**

My new reasoning is as follows:

The denominator is $\Delta x$. And since $x = 2x' \Rightarrow x' = \dfrac{x}{2}$, we have that $\dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta x'} = \dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta \frac{x}{2}} = \dfrac{2\Delta F'}{ \Delta x}$. If $\Delta x = 10^{-3}$, then $\dfrac{2\Delta F'}{10^{-3}}$. So, by this, **we can only say that $\dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta x'}$ is approximately double $\dfrac{\Delta F}{\Delta x}$ if $F' = F$, so that $\dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta x'} = \dfrac{2\Delta F'}{10^{-3}} = \dfrac{2\Delta F}{10^{-3}}$**.

Comment: One of your symbols does not render on my phone. It's the one before the third $\Delta$ from the left in the title.

Comment: @Shaun Before the third Delta? I'm not sure which one you're referring to. The symbols are, from left to right, Delta F' / Delta x' and Delta F / Delta x

Comment: That does not answer the question of what the intended symbol is (unless I've missed something).

Comment: @Shaun I edited my comment to explain the symbols in non-formatted text. Does that make sense?

Comment: See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S53Rq.jpg).

Comment: @Shaun There's nothing there, haha. It seems to be an aberration on your end.

Comment: @Shaun Actually, I *also* see it on my mobile device; in fact, mine displays as two question marks in black diamonds?

Comment: Possibly, yeah. How strange! There's also a question mark symbol that has no business being there. [Look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4d0B.jpg)

Comment: @Shaun Yes, the black diamonds with question marks are on my mobile device too! Very strange. Let me try to re-edit it.

Comment: @Shaun Did that change anything?

Comment: I'm afraid not!

Comment: @Shaun OF COURSE I was the one to break the website. Great! Sorry everyone. -_-

Comment: Hahaha! I think I fixed it.

Comment: @Shaun Yes! It is fixed on my mobile devices too!

Comment: @Shaun Any chance you know the answer to this? The bounty is about to expire with no answers.

Comment: I don't know how. I'm sorry. Good luck with it though!

Comment: Probably, I can help a bit. You may try to stand on a physical point of view and consider measurement units. E.g. say I'm driving the car 100 miles per hour. Sitting in the same car, a french tourist would say I'm driving 160 kilometers per hour. Thus changing coordinate system (miles to kilometers) I get almost twice as big gradient (consider velocity as a derivative of distance).

Comment: @guest Your physical example is a good one, but it doesn't directly answer the question that I'm interested in. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: An expression such as $(\partial F/\partial x, \partial F/\partial y)$ is called a pair. You are right it is not a triplet but neither is it a doublet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(clothing).

Comment: Facts like $x=2x'$, $y=2y'$ and indeed
  $\partial F'(x',y')/\partial x' = 2 \partial F(x,y)/\partial x$
  are facts about the change of coordinate system—
  about the relationship between $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$.
  They tell us nothing about the function $F$
  (except that it is sufficiently smooth to have those derivatives).

Comment: @Ali Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it difficult to deciver all your "thoughts", so I'll focus on the concrete question you ask. In the one dimensional case, what you are looking for is the chain rule. $\frac{\partial F(u(x))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F(u)}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x}$. In this higher dimensional example, $F'(x',y') = F(u(x'),u(y'))$ where $x = u(x') = 2x'$ (similar for $y$). So $\frac{\partial F'(x', y')}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial F(u(x'),u(y'))}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial F(u(x'),u(y'))}{\partial (u(x'))}\frac{u(x')}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial F(x, y)}{\partial x} \cdot 2$. The reason that the text uses approximate, is that when you calculate the approximate derivative $\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta x}$ for $\Delta x = 10^{-3}$ you will not get exactly 2.

I noticed in your thoughts that you asked whether $F(x/2, y/2) = F(x,y)/2$. This requiress some knowledge about the function $F$ which you do not have here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate on the last part with $\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta x}$? Please explain this in more detail.

Comment: Per definition: $\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta x} = \frac{F(x+\Delta x, y) - F(x,y)}{\Delta x}.$ Taking the limit $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ you get the partial derivative. Since this limit is not constant, taking $\Delta x$ very small, you'll get a value close to the true partial derivative.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how this answers my question of, if we're increasing the denominator by $10^{−3}$, then why doesn't the numerator also increase by approximately the same amount, so that the result approximately cancels out to result in approximately the same value as before? Please make this clear.

Comment: The denominator does not increase with $10^{-3}$. The text says: "In evaluating the rate of change with respect to, say, $x$, one increments $x$ by a small amount $\Delta x$, such as $\Delta x=10^{−3}$, and determines how much the function $F(x,y)$ changes in response to that small change in $x$." The $x$ in $F(x,y)$ is increased to $x+\Delta x$. It is correct that the difference in $\Delta F$ depends on $\Delta x$: $\Delta F \approx \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \Delta x$. (The Taylor Approximation)

Comment: Sorry @ThePointer, I didn't tag you

Comment: you don’t need to tag me; I’m still notified.

Comment: Oh, ok, that clarifies some serious misunderstanding that I had. The denominator is not changing; the denominator IS $\Delta x$. And since $x = 2x' \Rightarrow x' = \dfrac{x}{2}$, we have that $\dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta x'} = \dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta \frac{x}{2}} = \dfrac{2\Delta F'}{ \Delta x}$. If $\Delta x = 10^{-3}$, then $\dfrac{2\Delta F'}{10^{-3}}$. So, by this, **we can only say that $\dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta x'}$ is approximately double $\dfrac{\Delta F}{\Delta x}$ if $F' = F$, so that $\dfrac{\Delta F'}{\Delta x'} = \dfrac{2\Delta F'}{10^{-3}} = \dfrac{2\Delta F}{10^{-3}}$**.

Comment: Does that seem correct to you? The reasoning seems solid to me.

Comment: Sorry, was bussy yesterday @ThePointer.

It all is right, but you need to worry with the statement $F'=F$, because it is not the case that $F'(a,b) = F(a,b)$, but the evaluation $F'(x',y') = F(x,y)$ is correct. So, since $\Delta F'$ is defined over the change of $\Delta x$ and not $\Delta x'$, it is true that $\Delta F' = \Delta F$

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for the clarification. So how do we know that $\Delta F' = \Delta F$? And, related, what do you mean that $\Delta F'$ is defined over the change of $\Delta x$ and not $\Delta x'$? My apologies if I'm asking what might be obvious questions; I just want to ensure that I understand this, rather than having lingering doubts/uncertainties.

Comment: It's no problem @ThePointer, as I see that my wording was quite poor. It looks like the lingering doubts come form the hidden conventions in the notation $\frac{\Delta F'}{\Delta x}$. So to be precise: $\Delta x = 2\Delta x'$. Now, $\Delta F$ when $x$ is increased with $\Delta x$ equals $F(x+\Delta x, y) - F(x,y)$, putting $x=2x'$: $F(2x'+2\Delta x', 2y') - F(2x',2y')$. Now, replacing $F(2x',2y') = F'(x',y')$, we get $F'(x'+\Delta x', y') - F(x', y')$ which is $\Delta F'$

Comment: Ahh, YES! As I said in my main post, I strongly suspected that this real-analytic notation would be useful in understanding this! Thank you very much for the excellent answer!